# How to train full sentence-transformers model with dense layer in custom training loop

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning, sentence-transformers

I'm often using sentence-transformers as encoder and training a specific head for text classification. Because of some specific use-cases I want to customise fully the training loop and use pytorch lightning but I want to use full model as sentence-transformer.

sentence-transformer version 2.2.2 and torch 2.0.1

If I try to train the model created as:

```
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model_name, max_seq_length=256)
dim_size = word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension()
pooling_model = models.Pooling(
    dim_size,
    pooling_mode_cls_token=False,
    pooling_mode_mean_tokens=True,
)
dense = models.Dense(dim_size, len(label_map))
self.base_model = SentenceTransformer(
    modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model, dense]
)
```

To use directly the Dense layer to do my classification I get the following error when I try to optimize for the loss:

> one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [32, 54]], which is output 0 of TanhBackward0, is at version 1; expected version 0 instead

I understand that the problem is from the word embedding to the dense model from the traceback. Splitting the head, I can define the model as:

```
  word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model_name, max_seq_length=256)
  dim_size = word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension()
  pooling_model = models.Pooling(
      dim_size,
      pooling_mode_cls_token=False,
      pooling_mode_mean_tokens=True,
  )
  self.base_model = SentenceTransformer(
      modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model]
  )
self.activation_function = torch.nn.TanH(inplace=False)
self.final_linear = torch.nn.Linear(dim_size, len(label_map))

self.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(
     self.activation_function,self.final_linear
 )
```

To keep the same format as the the dense layer from sentence transformers.
Needs to change the forward pass to:

```
output = self.base_model(b_input)["sentence_embedding"]
output = self.classifier(output)
```

It works well.

By what I know this problem is because of overriding the same variable in the training loop (like I'm doing manually, 2 times output). I think that in torch 1.13.1 my fix would result in the same error but in torch 2.0.1 it works well. I don't understand why in sentence_transformers, using torch 2.0.1, it gives this error.

Any hint of how to train a full sentence-transformer model using a custom training loop and why I have this error?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've kept the class definition with the forward pass overwritten...